# Applying identical styling modifiers to either branch of a conditional if/else statement

Tags: swiftui

I have a simple view which is either a string or the same string with a superscript, something like the following which does work:

```swift
struct MyView : View {
  let both: Bool

  var body: some View {
    if both {
      Text("a") + Text("b").baselineOffset(6)
    } else {
      Text("a")
    }
  }
}
```

I am running into trouble when I try to apply some complicated styling to the result, e.g., `.bold().font(.largeTitle).background(.yellow)...`. I want to apply the styling regardless of which branch was taken but the best I was able to come up with requires me to repeat it for each branch of the conditional:

```swift
struct MyView : View {
  let both: Bool

  var body: some View {
    if both {
      (Text("a") + Text("b").baselineOffset(6)).bold().font(.largeTitle)....
    } else {
      (Text("a")).bold().font(.largeTitle)....
    }
  }
}
```

I think I sort of understand why this is needed having skimmed through result builder and view builder.  What's the canonical way to structure this so that I have a single instance of the modifiers and don't have to re-type and keep synced in two or more locations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use helper variable (calculable, or function) to prepare combined text (`cause you want to apply text-specific modifiers) and apply all text modifiers to a result, like

```
struct MyView : View {
    let both: Bool

    var body: some View {
        myText.bold().font(.largeTitle)
    }

    var myText: Text {
        if both {
            return Text("a") + Text("b").baselineOffset(6)
        } else {
            return Text("a")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works!  I've edited the answer slightly for correctness (the baselineOffset modifier was misplaced).

Answer (score 2):

Use `Group { }` around the views you want to change. It is an "invisible" kind of view that applies the modifiers to everything inside of it.

**Edit**: it doesn't work with `.baselineOffset()`, though (thanks @Asperi).

Try this:

```
            Group {
                if someState {
                    Text("Hello")
                } else {
                    Text("World")
                }
            }
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            .padding()
```

The `.font()`, `.foregroundColor()` and `.padding()` will be applied to either texts.

Comment: You wan't be able to apply `baselineOffset` to a Group because it is Text-only modifer

Comment: @Asperi: thank you! It works with `.font()`, but you are right about that modifier. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks both!  Yeah, I had tried Group which almost works but not really because it's missing some of the needed styling modifiers, e.g., it has `.font()` and `background()` but not `bold()`.